# Trouble with Convolution of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to calculate $C = A + B$ where $f_A(a) = 2 - 2a$ for $0 < a < 1$ and $f_B(b) = 2b$ for $0 < b < 1$. I think my integrand is $(2 - 2d)\cdot(2(c - d))$, but I'm not sure about the bounds. I know that $0 < d < 1$ but also that $c - 1 < d < c$. What are the correct bounds? Must c equal 1?

Comment: I doubt that "calculate $C = A + B$" is quite the right description of what you are trying to do.  You ask about bounds and an integrand, but the actual problem is not in focus.  Perhaps you are asking about the probability density of random variable $C$?  Using more words to setup the problem will allow to properly describe the goal.  Readers will then be able to devote the time to helping you solve the problem, rather than deconstructing your misunderstanding of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint support $(D,C)$ is a parallelogram with vertices

$(0,0);(1,1);(1,2);(0,1)$

Thus when $C\in(0;1)$ the integral is

$$f_C(c)=\int_0^c f_{CD}(c,d) d d$$

Thus when $C\in[1;2)$ the integral is

$$f_C(c)=\int_{c-1}^1 f_{CD}(c,d) d d$$

---

$d$ is an ugly letter for a rv...this confuses with the differential

Comment: Your attempt to answer this poorly phrased Question highlights, perhaps unintentionally, a nagging defect.  You introduce a random variable $D$ without definition, much as the OP introduced a parameter $d$ without definition.  I'm not sure what the OP had in mind, but most likely there is a mistaken change in notation mid-post.

Comment: The transformation is $C=A+B$ and $D=A.$